# Add element on certain columns in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to add an element (a circle) above some of the columns in a Highchart generated chart. In this chart, columns are stacked, to visually compare two series. But sometimes I need to draw a circle above some of these columns to show this year something special happened. I've tried to create a dummy serie, with bubbles but it doesn't work. So I believe that draw api is a better option, but I don't know how to calculate where I have to draw, to set element attributes x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.image() or more user friedly, scatter series which allows to define your own markers (like images). http://jsfiddle.net/cKKhF/

```
{

            type:'scatter',
            showInLegend:true,
            data:[10,9,11,11,8],
            marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }
        }
```